# PHP - Is it possible to grab a dynamically generated value in one file to use in another file in an if statement?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, if-statement

I currently have an inventory page that is populated by a MySQL database. I'm working on a page that can update the stock of an inventory item. I have three php files:

File One: Displays a dropdown of item names, the number in stock of the currently selected item, a dropdown option asking the user if they are adding or removing from the inventory, and a textbox for the change in number in stock. This page is a form.

File Two: Takes the currently selected dropdown item and grabs its number in stock from the database, echos it out to the page, and then takes whatever number is echoed out and prints it out as the displayed number in stock in a div in File One. I'm trying to use that value--the  number in stock that is returned on File One--in order to compare it to the amount changed textbox input, so users can't remove more then what is available.

File Three: The form action for File One. This is where I am attempting to code the if statement that compares the two values.

Here is the code for File Two:

```
$receivedString = null;

if ($_GET["item"] != ""){
    $receivedString = $_GET["item"];
}

if($receivedString != null){
    //Check connection
    $db = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) OR die ('Could not connect to SOIS MySQL server with error: ' . mysqli_connect_error());

    $query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT numInStock FROM SOISInventoryList WHERE id = $receivedString");

    if (!$query){
        echo "Could not find query.";
    }

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        echo $row['numInStock'];
    }
}
```

Here is the jQuery function for File Two:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get( "grab-num-in-stock.php", function( data ) {
        $( ".result" ).html( data );
    });
});

$(function(){
    $('#itemNameDropDown').change(function(){
        var SelectedItem = $(this).val();
        //Sending the selected item value to the php file as JSON
        //Assuming that the php file is setup to consume $_GET variables
        $.get('grab-num-in-stock.php', {"item": SelectedItem})
        .done(function(returnedData){
        //Assuming just a string is returned right now
        $('.numInStockCol').text(returnedData);
        });
    });
});
```

And here is File Three:

```
$receivedString = null;

if ($_GET["item"] != ""){
    $receivedString = $_GET["item"];
    echo "test";
}

else{
    echo "test failed";
}

if($receivedString != null){
    //Check connection
    $db = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) OR die ('Could not connect to SOIS MySQL server with error: ' . mysqli_connect_error());

    $query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT numInStock FROM SOISInventoryList WHERE id = $receivedString");

    if (!$query){
        echo "Could not find query.";
    }
}

if($_POST['adjustmentDropDown'] == 'remove'){
    $currentNumInStock = $row[0];

    if( $currentNumInStock >= $_POST['changeAmount']){
        echo "test 2";
    }

    else{
        echo "test 2 failed";
    }
}
```

I have attempted to use $item, $receivedString, and $row['numInStock']. I have also attempted to parse each of those from strings into ints using intval, and that did not appear to be the problem either. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Edit:

I've updated all of the above code to address issues brought up in the comments. My current issue is figuring out why File Three's "if ($_GET["item"] != "")" statement is returning nothing; the code is not echoing "test" as it should be. Any help is appreciated.

Since posting this originally I have also tried using a jQuery function to grab whatever is outputted in File One's number in stock div, but had no success there, either. Again, any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If a variable is in one file, and just that one file is loaded, then that variable could be considered to be 'scoped' to that file.

In File Three, you're attempted to access a value from File Two - and you're not finding it anywhere. That's because when you hit File Three, the only stuff that gets loaded is the stuff in File Three. Does that make sense? Your variables are scoped to what is actually being loaded - so it would make sense that File Three cannot access variables defined in another php page that has not been loaded.

Your options are to either pass the value along as a parameter or to run the database query again.

Also, [obligatory sql injection attack](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) warning.

Comment: I do have this chunk of code in my jQuery file, which loads File Two to every file in that folder. I wasn't sure if it was necessary or not to include it above, but I'll edit it in now:
$(document).ready(function(){
$.get( "grab-num-in-stock.php", function( data ) {
  $( ".result" ).html( data );
});
});

Comment: @madjaeg have a look at : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php this should help with the sql injection attack warning by Hamilton Lucas.

Comment: Looking at your code for File Three, you are running the query to get the numInStock but then you're not pulling the row off of the query result. As a result, $currentNumInStock is undefined. You just need to fetch the row from your query (after adding your where clause ;) and then assign $currentNumInStock to be $row[0].

Comment: @alettieri Thanks, I'll definitely check it out!

Comment: @HamiltonLucas Would the where clause be set up the same as the one I've got in File One? "SELECT numInStock FROM SOISInventoryList WHERE id = $receivedString"

Comment: I would expect it to be similar, yeah. You'll still need to pass the id to the page as a parameter. Just like in File One where you do `$receivedString = $_GET["item"];`.

Comment: @HamiltonLucas I added the exact same code I have in File Two, to File Three in order to make the where clause, and now instead of echoing out either test or error, it echos out nothing. I'm sure I did something wrong, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: I'm guessing either the `$receivedString` is null (so it isn't executing the necessary query) or the query is not returning results because `$receivedString` is not the id.

Use echo to diagnose the problem. Where you have conditionals (like `if($receivedString != null){` add an else clause and echo out the fact that $receivedString is null.

Comment: @HamiltonLucas It's not even getting through the first if:    if ($_GET["item"] != ""){ $receivedString = $_GET["item"]; }